# How can I point to a struct that is defined in another class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

In my application I want to have a list with entries. Some of these list entries have a sublist with more entries. For the entries I created a class that has a string for the text and a pointer which points to the sublist. These entries are put together to a list with a vector of pointers to the entries. Now I also want to have a selection variable that holds a number. So I put that vector together with the variable in a struct.

I tried it like this:

entry.cpp

```
class entry
{
    struct list; //prototype

    std::string text;
    struct* ptrToSubList;
}
```

in main.cpp

```
struct list
{
    std::vector<entry*> entryVector;
    int selection;
}
```

As you can see the question is which to define first because both need to know of each other already when created. The example above wouldnt compile and gives following error:

> connot convert entry::list* to main::list* in assignment

So, how can I point to a struct that is defined in another class?
Is this bad style?

Comment: see @crezefire's answer. full code would look like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31962867849837dc

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify your `list` struct to tell the compiler it actually belongs to the `entry` class as below:

```
struct entry::list {
// ...
};
```